# What causes bald spot between eye and ears on a cat?

Tags: cats, health, skin-condition, ears-nose-throat, hairloss

My cat is 7 months old and I've only got her for 2 weeks. She came with symmetrical bald spots on both sides of her face that ran from her ears to her eyes. What might have caused this?

She rarely grooms those spots, and I haven't been seeing her scratching those areas either.

[image]

Comment: Is this your first cat? Thin fur in that area is pretty normal, though it can look more pronounced on some cats, some colors, or at some angles. It's certainly concerning if you're not familiar with it, and of course you can always have your vet take a look to reassure you, but it's not abnormal.

Comment: Yeah, it's my first cat, so this is quite new to me.

Comment: Ask your vet next time you're in for reassurance, but don't worry about it. :) Welcome to cat ownership!

Comment: thanks! will do that next time visiting the vet.

Answer (score 7):

Cats naturally have thinner fur in that area, and if you look at the head at just the right angle, it can look almost bald like the photo. On some cats (especially those with darker fur, because of the contrast with the paler skin underneath) it's more noticeable than others. If you look at the cat from another angle, the fur usually looks fairly normal.

If the skin looks irritated, or if the cat is rubbing or grooming that area excessively, do consult a vet. Otherwise, it looks pretty normal to me.

Answer (score 6):

The phenomenon of hair loss in that area is called facial alopecia, and it's a normal pattern of hair loss when cats age. There are also scent glands around the face area, which cats enjoy rubbing on things, which may contribute even more to the hair loss in that area.

I should note though that sometimes hair loss in that area can also be related to some medical issue. But if it's medical related, there will probably be other symptoms like lesions in that area, or the cat is scratching that area.

Facial alopecia is said to typically appear in cats 14 to 20 months old, so your cat is a bit young to be showing it, but I wouldn't be too worried unless you notice any other symptoms. It very probably is the case that like humans, some cats just lose their hair unusually young without any other negative effects.